# Соединение Host-to-Host

Tags: c#, hosts

**Добрый день!**

Я читал про соединение **Host-to-Host** - как зашифрованный канал между двумя хостами, в котором весь трафик шифруется.  Меня интересует, как его реализовать на C# - подразумевает ли это обычный сокет, tcpClient или нужно какой-то еще объект использовать? И чем HtH отличается клиент-сервера?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Клиент и сервер - это условное разделение, которое подразумевает разные роли двух хостов, обменивающихся данными.

Кроме того, под клиент-сервер могут подразумевать вполне конкретный паттерн проектирования, который просто вводит фиксированные роли для двух приложений, но не накладывает ограничений на сам процесс передачи данных.

Host-to-host - любое соединение с одинаковыми логическими ролями хостов.

Физически же это все равно соединение между двумя хостами, с применением любой технологии - WCF или ручной работы с сокетами.

С другой стороны, под Host-to-Host могут иметь ввиду J.P. Morgan ACCESS<sup>®</sup> Host-to-Host<sup>SM</sup> - конкретную торговую марку конкретного протокола с конкретным шифрованием внутри.

Answer (score 0):

Host - это не Router. Client и Server оба являются хостами.

В данном случае (там где читал) под Host-to-Host подразумевалось вероятнее всего соединение между двумя PC или между PC и Server, но не между PC и Gateway (Router).